# Wordpress Footer Text PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently in the PHP file it has:

```
<?php if($myfooter_text){?>
    <?php echo of_get_option('footer_text'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    something else here
<?php } ?>
```

What I would like is for it to insert the footer text it finds using $myfooter_text but also add a link to the end of whatever has been pre filled in the footer text. I tried to use concatenation  with the following:

```
<?php echo of_get_option('footer_text') . '<a href="mylink.html">mylink</a>; ?>
```

However this still just shows the predefined footer text and not the additional content. Is there a way to do this? I'm aware it could be added in the footer area of the dashboard but this isnt what i want to do.

Comment: You missing closing quote `'` at end.

Comment: ^--« ... `'<a href="mylink.html">mylink</a>'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php echo of_get_option('footer_text'); ?> <a href="mylink.html">mylink</a>
```

You can concatenate them as well like this or do it your way and be sure you close all the quotes:

```
<?php echo of_get_option('footer_text') . '<a href="mylink.html">mylink</a>'; ?>
```